# Dropbox "java.lang.outofmemoryerror java heap space" when trying to upload a large file

Tags: java, dropbox

I'm new to this form,

I was getting an `OutOfMemoryError` while trying to upload a large file to dropbox via java dropbox sdk.

**Here is my scenario :**

Server A contains a file (>1GB) --> Server B opens a stream and passes that stream to dropbox api in java

**Here is my code :**

```
DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("dropbox/java-tutorial","en_US");
    DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(url_d);           
        // Upload Files to Dropbox
        String fileName = url_d.substring( url_d.lastIndexOf('/')+1, url_d.length() );
        DbxFiles.FileMetadata metadata = client.files.uploadBuilder("/"+fileName).run(url.openStream());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DbxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can anyone give me a solution.
Thank you.

Comment: Increse JVM max mem size and try again.

Comment: I do not have the access to change the mem size,because i had deployed it on Openshift free tire which gives ~256mb ram.

Comment: You better paster complete stacktrace. And more over where are references to that A file in your code, only some upload builder (but you want to DL it? or transfer it between servers?). Probably related, not seeing it whatsoever.